# How do I factor out a node module (using git)?

Tags: node.js, git, module, refactoring

Let's say I have a simple node project like this:

```
/
index.js
|
package.json
|
-- mymodules/my-awesome-module.js
|
-- node_modules
```

Let's also say that while I was developing this app I noticed that mymodules/my-awesome-module.js would be also useful for other projects.

So I'd like to factor it out – but I would also like to continue improving my module within this current project the same way I've done so far.

What I am stuck here with are two questions:

First, how do i manage to put my module in an npm-module, that is still part of my project tree?

Second, if I would manage to achieve that, how would I manage to turn that module into a separate git repo, also under the premise to still keep it in my project tree?

I hope, this post is somewhat comprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1 (easy way):**
If you want your file on multiple places on your current file system, you could use soft links, e.g:

```
$> ln -s mymodules/my-awesome-module.js /path-to-my-other-project/my-awesome-module.js
```

If you want to use a version control system on both projects, you could even use hard links (leave the `-s` option out).

*Attention*:
If you do it like that, you will always have to consider that a change (maybe done by git) will also affect all other projects using this file.

**Approach 2 (less easy, but better way):**
You could develop this file in it's own git repository and then use it as a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in all your other repositories.